# Не запускается работа службы

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь создать сервис, чтоб он постоянно работал, даже в фоне.

В приложении имеется 2 сервиса. Первый - для уведомлений. Второй - Для парсинга информации с сайта.

Первый сервис, для уведомлений, запускается и работает. Второй же, для парсинга информации - даже не запускается.

Структура моего приложения:

AutoStart.java :
- запускаем приложения чтобы работало в фоне:

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(intent1);
 }
}
```

Объявляю все это в Манифесте:

```
<service android:name="MyService" android:process=":myservice"></service>

    <receiver
 android:name=".AutoStart"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

В Главной Activity после завершения операции делаем старт сервиса для уведомлений:
`startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));`

Теперь делаю чтоб постоянно работал парсинг информации с сайта:

**Update.java**:

```
public class Update extends IntentService {
public Update(String name) {
    super(name);
}

 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}




@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Document doc = null;
       try {
           Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/aut.php")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();
           response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/login.php")
                   .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                   .data("nick", loginAuth
                        ,"pass", passAuth)
                   .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                   .timeout(30000).execute();


            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru").cookies(response.cookies()).get();
            Element blockRega = doc.select("div.foot").first();
         nav2Reg = blockRega.text();

         Element usInfo = doc.select("div.nav1").first();
         usName = usInfo.text();

         Elements kollMess = doc.select("a[href*=new_mess] div.nav2 font[color=red]");
         kollNewMess = kollMess.text();
         System.out.println("В СЕРВИСЕ");
         } catch (IOException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
         }

}





}
```

Делаю чтоб этот сервис запускался даже если в приложение не входили:

MyBroadReceiv.java :

```
public class MyBroadReceiv extends BroadcastReceiver {


  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, Update.class));
  }
}
```

Объявляю это в Манифесте:

```
        <service android:name="Update" android:process=":updateinfo"></service>
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadReceiv"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Прошу помочь мне разобраться. Не могу не как понять в чем дело.

Comment: Долго вчитывался, но так и не понял - который сервис не запускается-то?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не запускается тот который отвечает за постоянный парсинг информации с сайта - Update.java

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, проблема в том, что, как я понял, у вас два ресивера одного системного события. Наверняка один из них не вызывается просто. Попробуйте поместить запуск ваших сервисов в один и тот же ресивер.

Скорее всего выявить проблему можно простым логгированием запускающихся методов. Т.е. прописать

```
System.out.println("serviceName started");
```

в начале каждого метода. Так вы узнаете, какие методы отработали и в каком порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Если сервис, который отвечает за парсинг, должен у вас постоянно работать, то скоро вы столкнётесь с ещё одной проблемой. Он распарсит первый блок информации и умрёт как только дойдёт до конца метода onHandleIntent(). В этом случае пользуйтесь простым сервисом.

P.S. хотел добавить это в комментарий, но манны не хватило))

Comment: все верно. скорее всего сервис (IntentService) запустился, закончил работу и умер благополучно.